# DropdownButton Selected item isn't changing UI on SetState

Tags: flutter

I'm working with DropdownButtons in Flutter, and the UI isn't displaying the selected item. When the item is getting selected, it *is* being set in state (I have a check to make sure all values are set before going to the next page).

I have gone through everything and double-checked, there are no extra instances of `_category` being set inside the `build` method. The only reference to `_category` inside the `build` method is listed below, where it should be set via the call to `setState` inside of the button.

Here is my initialization of the variables:

```
class _MyClass extends State<MyClass>{
  ...
  late String _category ='';
  ...

  @override
  void init(){
    ...
    _category = '';
    ...
    super.initState();
  }
```

The `merchantCategories` variable is declared as such:

```
  final List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> merchantCategories = [
    const DropdownMenuItem(value: 'AUTOMOTIVE', child: Text('Automotive')),
    const DropdownMenuItem(value: 'HOME', child: Text('Home')),
    const DropdownMenuItem(value: 'FOOD', child: Text('Food')),
    const DropdownMenuItem(value: 'TRAVEL', child: Text('Travel')),
    const DropdownMenuItem(
        value: 'UTILITIES_AND_TELECOM', child: Text('Utilities and Telecom')),
    const DropdownMenuItem(value: 'ELECTRONICS', child: Text('Electronics')),
    const DropdownMenuItem(
        value: 'HEALTH_AND_BEAUTY', child: Text('Health and Beauty')),
    const DropdownMenuItem(
        value: 'ENTERTAINMENT', child: Text('Entertainment')),
    const DropdownMenuItem(value: 'RETAIL', child: Text('Retail')),
    const DropdownMenuItem(
        value: 'CHILDREN_AND_FAMILY', child: Text('Children and Family')),
    const DropdownMenuItem(
        value: 'OFFICE_AND_BUSINESS', child: Text('Office and Business')),
    const DropdownMenuItem(
        value: 'SERVICES_AND_SUBSCRIPTIONS',
        child: Text('Services and Subscriptions'))
  ];
```

Here is the button implementation, with DecoratedBox to display a border around the box.

```
...
                  DecoratedBox(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                      child: DropdownButton<String>(
                          underline: Container(),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                          hint: const Text('Select Merchant Category'),
                          items: merchantCategories,
                          onChanged: (value) => setState(() =>_category = value!)),
                  ),
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DropdownButton (per the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html)) has a value field that you seem to not be using. For example:

```
DropdownButton<String>(
 underline: Container(),
 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
 hint: const Text('Select Merchant Category'),
 items: merchantCategories,
 onChanged: (value) => setState(() =>_category = value!)),
 value: _category //what is missing
)
```

Side note, i have recently switched from the default implementation of input fields in flutter to a pub package that models input fields after the Angular FormControls. https://pub.dev/packages/reactive_forms

Comment: Interesting, I'm getting an error when I add `value:` to my DropdownButton - `Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value`. I don't get this error with `value:` removed.

Comment: Not sure if this would work but maybe instantiating _category as null instead of '', might need to change the variable definition to
`String? _category = null`
Also _category does not need be late since you are giving it a value immediately, late would be if you were starting with no assignment and then assigning a value